# White UI Automation compiled in x86 (XP) does not work for W7 (64bit)

Tags: user-interface, automation, white-framework

I'm trying on control a openfile dialog box through White.  I develop the test application in XP (x86) and it works fine.  The application an write into the selected filename combobox and click in the open button.

I tried to use the same test application in Windows7, and it seems that White is not able to write into the combobox nor click in the open button.  This is normal?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's normal when you trying to access 32bit app under test from 64bit test app.

I use xUnit with tests packed into class libraries. Forcing 'Platform target' to x86 does the trick - all White features work.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that White compiled in x86 does not input keystrokes nor clicks when run in Win7.  However, it does detect and set focus on selected UIitem.

I solved the issue simulating Windows keystrokes in c#.  hope it is useful for someone.